# Absolute path not shown properly in Jmeter with WDS

Tags: groovy, jmeter

For a scenario, I am using Jmeter with WebDriver Sampler. So for uploading a file, since I need to run in Jenkins, I have to pass the absolute path of file. To get the current path I defined following command in User Defined variable.

```
${__groovy(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__groovy(File.separator)}
```

When I log this its working fine. Its showing the file path correctly. But when I use this in WDS and try to log. I am getting the file path with all the backslash removed and unnecessary spaces.

```
C:\ram\file\part1\renamed.txt
```

It has to be printed like this, but instead

```
cramfilepartrename  d
```

It prints like this. Any idea what can be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your problem using latest versions of JMeter and WebDriver Sampler:

[image: JMeter WebDriver WDS Log]

1. Make sure to upgrade to JMeter 4.0 (or whatever is the [latest version](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) available at [downloads page](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi))
2. Make sure to upgrade WebDriver Sampler plugin to version 2.3 using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)
3. Make sure to use `WDS.log` shorthand to print the variable value